# How to compute the covariance across variables that are n dimensional

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

My data is of the following shape: 18x60x4
Basically, I have 18 variables, each described by a 60 point vector.
I have 4 example data points for each vector.

When I call np.cov(dataset) I get the following error:

```
shapes (18,60,4) and (4,60,18) not aligned: 4 (dim 2) != 60 (dim 1)
```

How can I resolve this? I couldn't find similar posts on this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you include code that can reproduce this error? (preferably bare minimum)

Comment: if you look at `help(mp.cov)` it does state that it takes a 1D or 2D matrix, try looking at other documentation on numpy to see if any are what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you should treat the 18 60-dimensional variables as `18*60=1080` variables. Then you can calculate the covariance. If `m` is your `(18,60,4)` array do the following:

```
covar = np.cov(m.reshape(18*60, 4)) #or np.cov(m.reshape(18*60, -1))
```

Then you can reshape again covar so that it shows the dimensionality of your variables:

```
covar = covar.reshape(18,60,18,60)
```